# hibernate deletes list relation when updating other list containing same objects

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In my application I have a setup like the following:

```
class A {
    String id;
    List<C> list;
}

class B {
    String id;
    List<C> list;
}

class C {
    String id;
}
```

which is mapped in hibernate like

```
<class name="A" lazy="false">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <list name="list" lazy="false" mutable="false">
        <key column="listA_id"/>
        <list-index column="listA_index"/>
        <many-to-many class="C"/>
    </list>
</class>

<class name="B" lazy="false">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <list name="list" lazy="false" mutable="false">
        <key column="listB_id"/>
        <list-index column="listB_index"/>
        <many-to-many class="C"/>
    </list>
</class>

<class name="C" lazy="false">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"/>
    </id>
</class>
```

All 5 tables (one for each class and 2 for the many-many-relations) are created as expected. The problem appears when I execute some code like the following:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c1 = new C();
C c2 = new C();
C c3 = new C();

<hibernatesession>.save(c1);
<hibernatesession>.save(c2);
<hibernatesession>.save(c3);

a.list.add(c1);
a.list.add(c2);

<hibernatesession>.save(a);

b.list.add(c1);
b.list.add(c3);

<hibernatesession>.save(b);
```

I followed the resulting SQL in a HSQL-log-file and found everything to be fine up until the last save. Saving b will result in the association between a and c1 being deleted from the many-many-tabel A_list. Fetching the objects a and b anew from the database will result in c1 and c3 being in b.list but only c2 in a.list.

Observations:
* There is no cascading in the game.
* switching the order of saving a/b will result in c1 getting deleted from the list of whoever gets saved first.
* Both lists are mapped with indexes.
* Both lists are mapped with different key/index-column names.
* hibernate deletes exactly those elements common to the lists

Can somebody explain me this behavior of hibernate and knows how to realize a respective mapping correctly?

Thx in advance!!!
Salsolatragus

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a many-to-many mapping to Class C so that it is a bidirectional relationship. Perhaps by being explicit about the "parent" relationships, it will know to keep more than one relationship rather than delete the first one as you have explained.

```
<class name="C" lazy="false">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <list name="listA" lazy="false" mutable="false" inverse="true">
        <key column="listC_id"/>
        <many-to-many class="A"/>
    </list>
    <list name="listB" lazy="false" mutable="false" inverse="true">
        <key column="listC_id"/>
        <many-to-many class="B"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

Comment: I tried, but its still the same phenomenon... except, that he is _not_ deleting the backwards references! So c1 keeps its reference on a _and_ b, while either of those looses its reference to c1. Somehow this appears even stranger to me...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug. Lessons learned: If you have strange correlations between certain Collections in hibernate, check first if you're accidentally using the same Java instance for them... A couple of hours pairDebugging thru hibernate at last led us to the right guess. Tricky thing. Problem solved.

Thx for you hint Brad!